# Only get the latest build from a branch on deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When doing a `deployment` job with a CI trigger and `resources.pipelines` that are defined like

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: thumbnailGenerator
      project: myServices
      source: thumbnail-generator CI
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - master
```

The `deployment` job downloads the latest build of the pipeline (which may be a PR) rather than the last build from `master`.  Is there a way of making it only download the specific branches when doing a CI build?

I haven't explored it yet, but I am thinking based on this behaviour it will always do the latest builds for all the pipelines regardless.

Answer (score 0):

There's a property called `branch` on the pipeline object

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: thumbnailGenerator
      project: myServices
      source: thumbnail-generator CI
      branch: master
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - master
```